# Does res.end() not ends the http.createServer() callback function?

Tags: node.js, http

I have question about res.end() method available with require("http).createServer().
So the tutorial I was watching the following worked:

```js
require("http").createServer((req, res) => {
  if (req.url === "/") {
    res.end("Here is home Page");
  }
  if (req.url === "/about") {
    res.end("Here is about page");
  }
  res.end("404 Page not found");
}).listen(8080);
```

But when I try to run the snippet it give the following error:

```
ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END
```

I know why this is happening.
My question is why res.end() is not stopping the createServer() callback.
If you know please give some advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`res.end()` is JUST a function call like any other function call.  It does not affect the Javascript flow of control in your function at all.  It terminates the http request, but not the function you're in. If there are lines of code after it in the function, they will execute.  If you want to terminate the execution of the request handler, then use a `return` after the `res.end()` or structure an `if/else` logic so it only executes one thing and then is done.

For example, you can do either of these:

```
require("http").createServer((req, res) => {
  if (req.url === "/") {
    res.end("Here is home Page");
  } else if (req.url === "/about") {
    res.end("Here is about page");
  } else {
    res.end("404 Page not found");
  }
}).listen(8080);
```

or

```
require("http").createServer((req, res) => {
  if (req.url === "/") {
    res.end("Here is home Page");
    return;
  }
  if (req.url === "/about") {
    res.end("Here is about page");
    return;
  }
  res.end("404 Page not found");
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer[https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00].

Comment: @TalhaAli - Glad to help.  Since it looks like you may be new here, if this answered your question and you want to indicate that to the community here, you can click the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you a few reputation points.